# sqldeveloper file open dialog freeze

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

When I try to open a file using the file open dialog, `sqldeveloper` freezes for almost a minute. After that the dialog opens at the user temp folder.

I think it is trying to access some unavailable network location:

[image: promon]

However, I can't figure out how to make it "forget" that location. I tried to select a local file in the dialog, but next time all repeats.

Comment: what version are you running? if i open a file, and then go to open another file, it starts in the directory i last browsed to. you can also try using the view > files panel, or just drag and drop the file from explorer to the worksheet

Answer (score 0):

sql developer was taking a long time to open files dialog. I found out that it was because it is opening local temp folder which has a huge amount of files. Guess what, these files are being generated by sql developer. They are name amcXXXX.tmp.
I didnt find how to avoid its generation though.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened because SQLDeveloper was picking up a newer system-wide JDK (11 in my case). Pinning it to JDK 1.8 has helped:
Edit
`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\21.4.3\product.conf`
and add this line:
`SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201`

Of course, adjust to the location of your 1.8 JDK (above is standard for the last royalty-free Oracle JDK)